# Passing an object through multiple classes neatly

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

I have a logfile object that I would like to effectively be omnipresent in the rest of my code so that it can pick up comments throughout the code.  How can I go about coding this into a nice OOP format?

At the moment I sort of have instantiate it in the first class it's used in and then pass it to every other class when they are instantiated (I haven't even started to think about trying to hand the log back once I've finished using a class.  This clearly seems unnecessarily messy!

```
class LogFile(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.log = []
        pass

    def write_log(self, data):
        self.log.append(data)

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = LogFile()
        self.do_some_stuff(stuff)

    def do_some_stuff(self, stuff):
        ...
        b = B(self.logger)
        b.do_some_more_stuff(stuff)
        self.logger.write_log(stuff)

class B(object):

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def do_some_more_stuff(self, stuff):
        ...
        ...
        self.logger.write_log(more_stuff)

item = A()
item.do_some_stuff(stuff)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I usually don't like to use Singletons, but for things like logging it is the easiest solution I know.

And the simplest way to implement it in python is to use the module-level variable, in the module `mylogger.py`:

```
class LogFile(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.log = []
        pass

    def write_log(self, data):
        self.log.append(data)

logger = LogFile()
```

And in the another module:

```
from mylogger import logger

class A(object):

    def do_some_stuff(self, stuff):
        ...
        logger.write_log(data)
```

Python's standard [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) uses similar approach having the `root` logger [defined as a module-level variable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1669).